# What's the meaning of "tasse d'interesse"?

Tags: word-meaning

In a conversation between a student and a banker telling her that there's an account for students which has "tasse d'interesse" 
can anyone tell me what's this?

Comment: The correct phrase is "tasso d'interesse". Have you looked it up in a dictionary?

Comment: http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano-Inglese/T/tasso_3.php

Comment: @DaG: Potrebbe essere "tasse" come plurale del femminile "tassa"? Cioè, sarebbe possibile che il banchiere abbia usato questo termine (forse in modo impropio)?

Comment: @Charo Non credo proprio, *tassa* e *tasso* sono parole diverse e spero proprio che un banchiere non le confonda...

Comment: Confermo, @Charo, è veramente molto improbabile “tasso d'interesse” è una frase fatta (o più tecnicamente un'espressione polirematica), come “momento d'inerzia” o “calcio di rigore”.

Comment: In alternativa a "tasso" potrebbe aver detto "tassi d'interesse" se si riferiva ad un discorso generale sull'andamento dell'economia

Comment: Btw...it is very  unlikely that a (banchiere) banker is involved in this issue, it most likely is a bank employee.

Answer (score 5):

***[Tasso](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tasso_d%27interesse)*** (plural ***tassi***) is the term we use to indicate a ***rate***. *Tasso di interesse* is the *rate of interest* which, in your case,  refers to the interest the student can earn by  deposting money into the account the bank employee is proposing.

***Not to be confused*** (but foreigners often confuse it) with:

***[Tassa](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tassa)*** (plural ***tasse***) is the term we use  to refer to ***tax/taxes***, (an amount of) money paid to the government that is based on your income or the cost of goods or services you have bought.

(Wikipedia)